# Not able to see special subject "AllAuthenticatedInTrustedRealms" while mapping security roles to users in Websphere 8.0.0.9

Tags: security, jakarta-ee, websphere, websphere-8, jaas

We are not able to see " AllAuthenticatedInTrustedRealms" option in Map special subjects while we are mapping the security role to users in Websphere 8.0.0.9 where as in Websphere 8.0.0.8 we have it.

Is there any configuration needed to see that option for mapping the security roles to users for our web application???

I suspect that there may be some configuration missing.

Please help here. Appreciations for your earlier reply.

Comment: `AllAuthenticatedInTrustedRealms` means exactly the same as `AllAuthenticated` if you have single security domain. This option will only be visible, if you will have multiple security domains configured in the cell. So use `AllAuthenticated`.

Comment: Thanks for reply Gas, we don't see 'AllAuthenticated' too. we have only '1.None 2. All Authenticated in application realm 3.Everyone' . First two are not getting authenticated for 3.Everyone its got authenticated but TAI not getting invoked.
@Gas

Comment: `2. All Authenticated in application realm` this one should work.

Comment: I checked with that option, but with our existing configuration its not working. We have only one realm which is trusted and another one default realm file based which marked as untrusted, if I use  **2. All Authenticated in application realm** then do I need to any more configuration changes to work out. Can you elaborate it?
@Gas

Comment: Its hard to tell. You have to describe more your configuration. How did you create realms, why you have multiple, why default is marked as untrusted, did you map correct security domain to your application server, etc.You provided too little info about your configuration.

Comment: Sorry for late information, we don't have any security domains, under global security we have LDAP registry realm which we marked as trusted, and we not at all using default realm so may be marked that as untrusted. So we use to do all authentication with LDAP registry only. Hope this will clear you to point out the actual problem @Gas

Comment: Are you able to log in to any application e.g admin console with various LDAP users?

Comment: Yes we are able to login to admin console with some of LDAP users which belongs to that particular group..

Answer (score 1):

The `AllAuthenticatedInTrustedRealms` is only available if you have other external realms defined (independent of whether you define other security domains).  External realms are defined from the **Federated Repositories** configuration page by clicking **Trusted authentication realms - inbound**.  If you add an external realm to this list, you should then see the option for `AllAuthenticatedInTrustedRealms`.

If you have this defined (like in your WAS 8.0.0.8 case so that the configurations are identical), then you might want to open a PMR with IBM to address it.